# How to use double coordinates to draw rectangles in Canvas (Android)

Tags: android, canvas

I'm using Canvas to draw figures by means of rectangles. These figures are modeling real world shapes, so the measures are real numbers (double variables). Thus, what I do is scale the dimensions and then convert the double variables to int variables. The problem is that because of the "rounding" in the conversion step, sometimes the figure is not shown properly. How can a figure be drawn accurately in this case?

Here is the code used to draw a rectangle:

```
x0 = viewWidth/2 + (int)((-figRealWidth/2 + figureRectangles[i].getX0()) * drawFactor);
y0 = viewHeight/2 + (int)((-figRealHeight/2 + figureRectangles[i].getY0()) * drawFactor);
x1 = x0 + (int)(figureRectangles[i].getWidth() * drawFactor);
y1 = y0 + (int)(figureRectangles[i].getHeight() * drawFactor);
canvas.drawRect(x0, y0, x1, y1, paintRectangle);
```

Comment: According to the documentation, drawRect takes float arguments, not integers. Why do you insist to use integers? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: Yeah, right! I overlooked it. Thanks for the comment peedee.